# MYSQL AUTO INCREMENT RANGE

Tags: mysql

Hello guys i want to use an auto-increment number with PK for one of my column which starts from 000001 and ends with 100000 mean i want to have just one Luck or 100,000 users in my website not more any one pleease? I am using mysql php admin interface (GUI).

Comment: I don't think in mysql there is rang for auto complete column but you can do by procedure writing or you can handle by you server side language.

Comment: what about CMD commands

Answer (score 0):

The closest data type would be a Medium INT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), but you would still have to limit to 100,000 via code on insert or some sort of MySQL procedure as mentioned by Neo.

Comment: thanks guys for answers where is the problem in this code :           <?php 
                           mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error());
  $count=mysql_query('SELECT COUNT($queryrun) FROM properties'); ?>
        <div>Your Query Found <strong><?php echo $Result=mysql_result($count, 0)
   ?></strong> Properties in Your Selected Location</div><br>

Comment: The first error is that you're posting this question in a comment, not a new question, the second error is that you're using a deprecated php module.  The third error is that you have no protection from SQL injection.  The fourth is probably that $queryrun has a value that isn't * or a column name in the table.